# Autowire Jdbc template

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to auto-wire JDBC template and I'm getting a null pointer exception (template is null). What could be the problem?

```
@Autowired
template JdbcTemplate;
```

This is my application context xml:

```
<bean ..>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

            <context:component-scan base-package="igate.dto" />
                <context:component-scan base-package="igate.dao" />
                    <context:component-scan base-package="igate.service" />
                        <context:component-scan base-package="igate.controller" />
                <context:component-scan base-package="igate.logs" />
                    <context:component-scan base-package="igate.testcases" />


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean> 


    <bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.21.17.5:1521:oraten" />
        <property name="username" value="lab01trg21" />
        <property name="password" value="lab01oracle" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: To start you don't need 6 `<component-scan>` elements. You need just one with comma separated values: `<context:component-scan base-package="igate.dto, igate.dao, igate.service, ..." />`

Comment: Is this xml config a dispatcher servlet context xml config or a root application context initializer xml config? Remember if the first is true you can't reference jdbc template from root webapp context app services.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of this code:

```java
@Autowired
template JdbcTemplate;
```

You need:

```java
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate template;
```

Answer (score 4):

1. The bean you try to inject in is not in the spring context;
2. No setter for the JdbcTemplate
3. You try to use the template in the constructor before the template is injeted

Answer (score 4):

One reason for this error is to mix autowiring with manual 
creation of beans.

For instance, you have a service class that autowires a bean.

```
@Service
public class CarService {

    @Autowired
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    // service code
}
```

But later intead of

```
@Autowired
private CarService carService;
```

you do:

```
CarService carService = new CarService();
```